# Help with integral $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried to solve by parts but it did not help.

Comment: Is $tgx$ $tan(x)$ ?

Comment: yes, it is. There is differenсe?

Comment: No, just clarifying ! Beside integration by parts, did you try any substitution ? Is this homework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$u = \tan x \implies du = \sec^2 x dx \iff \,dx = \frac{du}{\sec^2 x} = \frac{du}{1 + \tan^2 x} = \frac{du}{1+ u^2}$$

Substituting gives us $$\int \dfrac{du}{(1 + u^2)u^{1/2}}$$

Comment: Let me know if you need any additional help.

Comment: no, thanks, all is good
but in the future
I will be grateful if you help me

Comment: I surely will, if I can! ;-)

Comment: slmkarta It's a bit more involved than Sami's (currently incorrect) solution. See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28dx%29%2F%28sqrt%28\tan+x%29%29) and how it handles the integral from where I left off.

Comment: I am use $$t = \sqrt{u}$$ and then $$\int \frac{dt}{1+t^4} $$ like tablical integral with $$ 1^2 +b^2$$.

Comment: Yes, that's good...you're on the right track.

Comment: when will I receive 15 ptc, I can do it)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13737/discussion-between-slmkarta-and-amwhy)

Comment: I've got to go and lecture now (I'm going to have to run to the classroom to make it in time for class.) I'll check back this afternoon to see if you're around, okay?

Comment: okey, i just pushed the button to to see what it

Answer (score 2):

$u^2=\tan x\Longrightarrow 2udu=\sec^2xdx=(1+\tan^2x)dx=(1+u^4)dx\Longrightarrow dx=\frac{2u}{1+u^4}du$. So, $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt\tan x}dx=2\int\frac{du}{1+u^4}=2\int\frac{du}{(1+\sqrt 2u+u^2)(1-\sqrt 2u+u^2)}$$
$$=2\int\frac{Au+B}{1+\sqrt 2u+u^2}du+2\int\frac{Cu+D}{1-\sqrt 2u+u^2}du:=2I+2J$$ 
where $$I=\int\frac{Au+B}{1+\sqrt 2u+u^2}du,\,J=\int\frac{Cu+D}{1-\sqrt 2u+u^2}du $$
with $A=-\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}$, $C=\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}$, $A=B=\frac{1}{2}$. $$I=-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{\sqrt2u-2}{1+\sqrt 2u+u^2}du=-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{(\sqrt2u+2-4)}{1+\sqrt 2u+u^2}du$$$$=-\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{(\sqrt2u+2)}{1+\sqrt 2u+u^2}du+\int\frac{du}{(u+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2})^2+\frac{1}{2}}$$ $$=-\frac{1}{4}\ln (1+\sqrt2u+u^2)+\sqrt2\arctan(u+\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}).$$ $J$ can be computed similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: set $\tan(x)=t^2.$