# Finding $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx = ?$$

I tried:

$$\int \frac{\sin^2 x + \cos^2x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx = \int \left(\frac{\sin^2x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}+\frac{\cos^2x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}\right)dx = \\
\int \sqrt{\sin^3x\cos x}dx + \int \sqrt{\frac{\cos^5x}{\sin x}}dx $$

Now solving the first one individually:

$$\int \sqrt{\sin^3x\cos x}dx = \int \sqrt{\sin x \cos x}*\sin x dx = \int \sqrt{\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}}*\sin x dx = \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \sqrt{\sin(2x)}*\sin dx $$

I tried to integrate by parts but didn't get anywhere. Still, here it is:

$$\int \sqrt{\sin(2x)}*\sin dx $$

$v = \sqrt{\sin(2x}$

$dv = \frac{\cos(2x)dx}{2\sqrt{\sin(2x)}}$

$du = \sin x dx$

$u = -\cos(x)$

$$1/\sqrt{2} [\sqrt{\sin(2x}*-\cos (x) + 1/2 \int \frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{\sin(2x)}}*\cos x dx]$$

I just keep going in circles. What do I do?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/719909/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2318042/42969 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B%5Ctan%20x%7D%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: You can search with approach0, BTW.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating the indefinite integral $ \int \sqrt{\tan x} ~ \mathrm{d}{x}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828640/evaluating-the-indefinite-integral-int-sqrt-tan-x-mathrmdx) Note that your integral is $g$ or $J$ from the answers from there and just extract it as $2g=(y+g)-(y-g)$.